# light effects of electric current

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, thermal-radiation

In german high school textbooks and curriculua, the distinction of following main sorts of effects of electric current is usual: magnetic, heat, light and chemical.

My question is, whether the glow of a light bulb or a glowing wire count as light effect or if it is only a special case of the heat effect.

If the glowing wire counts as heat effect, only LEDs and fluorescent lamps are left over for the light effect. But recombination or ionization seem to be quite indirect effects of el. current, since they are dependent to special gases or solids.

Comment: Who is it that makes these distinctions? What about electromagnetic effects (like radio waves) - do they count as light or as magnetic effect. And what about the electrostatic forces that a current can experience (think electron current in vacuum tube). This seems a poorly framed question. Can you explain more about the background?

Answer (score 1):

A hot object will glow like a light bulb, even in the absence of an electric current. As such, I think that the glowing is a "heat effect".